# AI characters in Unity with Photon View

Tags: network-programming, unity-game-engine, photon

I am building a small game in Unity using Photon multiplayer code and Rain Indy AI. Before adding AI, all game objects where in sync, but the new AI characters seem to be controled by each game instance individualy.

I have had a some what simmilar issue with bullets but here i just turn the shoot script of the prefab on and off, on instansing a player.

What is the best way to make shure only one instance of AI code is running? Do i need to convert the AI characters into prefabs as well?

Answer (score 0):

Instancing the the AI characters as a prefab and enabeling the the RAINAgent component did the trick.

```
GameObject SimpleAICharacter = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("SimpleAICharacterfab",
new Vector3(Random.Range(-50,50),5,Random.Range(-50,50)), Quaternion.identity, 0);

RAINAgent AIController = SimpleAICharacter.GetComponent<RAINAgent>();
AIController.enabled = true;
```